# How to upload multiple files by using AutoIt?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am using below code:

```
ControlFocus("File Upload","","File1")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","File1",'"C:\Users\Desktop\image1.png" "C:\Users\Desktop\image1.png" "C:\Users\Desktop\image2.png" "C:\Users\Desktop\image3.png" "C:\Users\Desktop\image4.png" "C:\Users\Desktop\image5.png" "C:\Users\Desktop\image6.png" "C:\Users\Desktop\image7.png" "C:\Users\Desktop\image8.png" "C:\Users\Desktop\image9.png"')
ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")
```

I have run this code files getting, but not stored. Entered in manually files stored

what was the problem.If any one help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how to automate a window is shown below. In order to save content to a file you need first to open it.

```
var autoit = new AutoItX3Lib.AutoItX3();
var windowWait = autoit.WinWaitActive("[CLASS:#32770]", "", 10);

Console.WriteLine("...Surviving the IE security window handler");
//  autoit.WinWaitActive("Beveiligingswaarschuwing", "Ja");

autoit.ControlSend("Beveiligingswaarschuwing", "", "", "{TAB}");

autoit.Sleep(500);
autoit.ControlSend("Beveiligingswaarschuwing", "", "", "{ENTER}");

autoit.Sleep(500);
autoit.ControlSend("Beveiligingswaarschuwing", "", "", "{TAB}");

autoit.Sleep(500);
autoit.ControlSend("Beveiligingswaarschuwing", "", "", "{ENTER}");

autoit.Sleep(500);
autoit.ControlSend("Beveiligingswaarschuwing", "", "", "{TAB}");

autoit.Sleep(500);
autoit.ControlSend("Beveiligingswaarschuwing", "", "", "{ENTER}");


autoit.Sleep(500);
autoit.ControlSend("Beveiligingswaarschuwing", "", "", "{TAB}");


autoit.Sleep(500);
autoit.ControlSend("Beveiligingswaarschuwing", "", "", "{ENTER}");
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 2):

Code to upload multiple files using AutoIt

```
    ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
    ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","""C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg""""C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg""")
    ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

Comment: Working fine for me. Thanks.